Question on QuantLib Python DatedOISRateHelper fairRate
I'm wondering if this is intended in DatedOISRateHelper. Referring to executable code below, 1Y OIS maturity date is 22nd Dec 2025 (21st and 22nd Dec fall on weekend). However when I try to price OIS that starts on 20th Dec 2024 and ends on 22nd Dec 2025, the fairRate() doesn't return input of 0.0396015. Shouldn't we able to price back fairRate 0.0396015 based on input to DatedOISRateHelper?
Note: I will be able to get correct fairRate if I use OISRateHelper with "1Y" as input; or DatedOISRateHelper with "20th Dec 2025" as input.
import QuantLib as ql

today = ql.Date(20, 12, 2024)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

maturity_dates = [
    ql.Date(27, 12, 2024), ql.Date(20, 1, 2025), ql.Date(20, 2, 2025), ql.Date(20, 3, 2025),
    ql.Date(22, 4, 2025), ql.Date(20, 5, 2025), ql.Date(20, 6, 2025), ql.Date(22, 9, 2025),
    ql.Date(22, 12, 2025), ql.Date(22, 6, 2026), ql.Date(21, 12, 2026),
]

rates = [
    0.0433, 0.04337, 0.04342, 0.043045, 0.0426125, 0.042335, 0.04184, 0.04086, 0.0396015, 0.038455, 0.0378795,
]

ois_helpers = [
    ql.DatedOISRateHelper(
        today,
        tenor,
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)),
        ql.Aonia(),
        paymentFrequency=ql.Annual,
    )
    for tenor, rate in zip(maturity_dates, rates)
]

ois_curve = ql.PiecewiseSplineCubicDiscount(0,ql.Australia(), ois_helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
discount_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ois_curve)
swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(discount_curve)

schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(
    effectiveDate=today,
    terminationDate=ql.Date(22, 12, 2025),
    tenor=ql.Period("1Y"),
    calendar=ql.Australia(),
    convention=ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    terminalDateConvention=ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    rule=ql.DateGeneration.Forward,
)

ois_swap = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap(
    ql.OvernightIndexedSwap.Receiver,
    1_000_000,
    schedule,
    0.1,
    ql.Actual365Fixed(),
    ql.Aonia(discount_curve),
)
ois_swap.setPricingEngine(ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(discount_curve))

print(
    ois_swap.startDate(),
    ois_swap.maturityDate(),
    f"{ois_swap.fairRate():.9f}",
    ois_swap.fixedLegBPS(),
    discount_curve.discount(ois_swap.maturityDate()),
)
```


The swap inside the DatedOISRateHelper used to bootstrap the curve are currently instantiated with rule=ql.DateGeneration.Forward, which makes your ois_swap different from the quoted swap.  If you use the same rule for ois_swap, you'll get the expected fair rate.
Starting from version 1.37, due for January 2025, you'll be able to specify the date generation rule as Forward when creating the helper.  Note that, instead of the constructor of DatedOISRateHelper (which will be deprecated) you'll have to build the helpers by calling the static method OISRateHelper.forDates.

Thank you Luigi. I tried to change the DateGeneration rule to Backward and I've got the expected fairRate().
